# Function to reduce outliers

Tags: r, function, outliers

I am working with support vector machines and want to reduce outliers. 
So I have a function to reduce outliers to 70% of there original value.
I find this method better than winsorization as it doesn't assign lots of data points the same value, it creates a more even spread.

Function to reduce outliers -

```
outlier <- function(x) {
  x[x < quantile(x,0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE) | x > quantile(x,0.75, na.rm = TRUE) + 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)] <- (x * 0.7)
  x
}
```

The problem is the function works on some columns, but produces this error messages on other columns.

Warning message:

> In x[x < quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE) | 
>   : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the length issue, use `ifelse` so you know you'll be creating a new vector with the same length as the original `x`. Also, with complex conditions, try breaking them up into smaller pieces. Unless you're 100% certain about the order of operations, it's easy to go wrong, and I'm not sure your current logic does what you want:

```
outlier <- function(x) {
    lower_limit = quantile(x,0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    upper_limit = quantile(x,0.75, na.rm = TRUE) + 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    is_outlier = (x < lower_limit) | (x > upper_limit)
    print(paste("Replacing", sum(is_outlier), "outliers"))
    ifelse(
        is_outlier,
        x * 0.7,
        x
    )
}
```

Comment: Whoa, it even prints the number of outliers replaced. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, checking again, it does look like your existing syntax was producing the right results, but personally I always break multiple conditions up and wrap them in parentheses to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because the length of vectors on LHS and RHS of `<-` inside the function is not the same. Here's the correct way -

```
outlier <- function(x) {
  idx <- (x < quantile(x,0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)) | (x > quantile(x,0.75, na.rm = TRUE) + 3 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  x[idx] <- x[idx] * 0.7
  x
}
```